# Sliding pages with url change...how is that possible?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Today I was facinated from the following website http://soulwire.co.uk/
If clicked on the menu the site changes url and slides down. I've never seen such thing and I'm asking myself how that is working. JQuery can do such things but with setting anchors...

Somebody know how that works?

Comment: it is a great web site http://soulwire.co.uk/

Comment: it is pushState of history object. comes with HTML 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a peak into their .js code, and this is what they're using:

```
this.page.identifier=window.location.pathname;
this.page.url=window.location.href+"#!"+window.location.pathname;
```

So they actually stay on the same page, but they just change the url in the address bar.

Comment: thanks a lot...i thought that wasn't working with javascript...so this is just a fake ;-P

Comment: Yeah, I just don't think it can be done differently. Unless you load the next page, and slide after it loads, but that's just slow.

Comment: Actually the site uses HTML5 History API, as you can check your self that there is no 'hash-bang' in the URL.

Comment: @tungd I suggest you make it an answer and it can get re-assigned :)